# MariaDB: Finding if a circular radius from a latitude and longitude point, intersects a polygon

Tags: mariadb, geo

I'm building a google map search piece, whereby I can specify a location and a 'radius'. I then am trying to get results of what defined regions (defined as polygons in my DB), that the radius search intersects.

I'm currently using the following query (php code for some clarity):

```
$km = ($miles * 1.852) * 1000;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Regions WHERE ST_Intersects(poly, ST_BUFFER(ST_GeomFromText('POINT({$lat} {$lng})'), {$km}))"
```

The Regions database is set up with a "poly" polygon field, that holds the polygon data of the latitude and longitude values. However, in searching it from a 5-mile radius, I'm receiving all the polygons in the database.

I've based the query on some other loose answers I've found, but now I'm at a bit of a loss as to what I might be doing wrong. The majority of issues that I've found online are to find specific locations within a polygon or radius, but here I need to know if my radius search intersects the polygons I've created.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having a similar problem, I found the issue(s) I was having.

When storing the 'polygon' value in the database, you have to provide the values as "longitude latitude", whereas I was storing them the other way around. I presume this is because lng/lat is x/y format.

I also then used methods from a class found here https://github.com/bcalik/php-circle-to-polygon to generate a circular polygon. Then used it as such:

```
SELECT id FROM Regions WHERE ST_Intersects(poly, GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((" . implode(",", $circle) . "))', 0))
```

Where `$circle` is an array of `$longitude $latitude` string values.

The ST_BUFFER method might still work, but now I have it working I don't plan on messing with it anymore :)